# 80s movie where aliens suck people into the ground

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

I barely remember anything about this, other than that the aliens suck people into the ground. It's not *Dune* and it's not *Tremors*. I think it might have been a children's movie. Also I think the aliens might have been body snatchers or making clones. One specific scene is when a scientist in a hazard suit is using a metal detector in a sand pit and then get sucked under.

Comment: The man with the metal detector sounds like a scene from "Blood Beach", but while it's an 80's movie it's decidedly _not_ a children's movie, nor about aliens.

Comment: https://timemachine.fandom.com/wiki/Time_Kid is 2002, which is too late.

Comment: *Blood Beach* was my first thought too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is Tobe Hooper's ***[Invaders from Mars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invaders_from_Mars_(1986_film))*** (1986).

> *Invaders from Mars* is a 1986 American science fiction horror film, directed by Tobe Hooper from a screenplay by Dan O'Bannon and Don Jakoby. It is a remake of the [1953 film of the same name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invaders_from_Mars_(1953_film)), and is a reworking of that film's screenplay by Richard Blake from an original story by John Tucker Battle.

A large Martian spacecraft lands near an American town and burrows its way underground. The aliens then begin taking control of the town's inhabitants via needle-like brain implants inserted through the back of the neck.

People under the aliens' control behave oddly and eat strange things, which may be why the film reminded you of *Invasion of the Body Snatchers*. The main protagonist is a 12-year-old boy, which may be why you thought this could be a children's movie.

Regarding the specific scene you mentioned, at around 45 minutes in, two male NASA employees, wearing orange uniforms and carrying metal detectors, inspect the huge sandpit where the spacecraft landed and are swallowed up by a sandy vortex, which closes behind them after they've disappeared from view. The following excerpt from an [IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091276/plotsummary/) plot summary describes the scene in question:

> Soon, Linda Magnusson finds David on the run, and he shows her the alien cave. When he gets to the location, however, the cave has disappeared. He insists they go to Copper Hill, but the spaceship is also gone. **In the distance, they hear George Gardner send two men with metal detectors into the sandpit at Copper Hill. David and Linda watch as a circular opening in the earth swallows the men.** Linda and David drive away and narrowly miss hitting a school bus driven by Mrs. McKeltch.

There's a brief shot of the two men with metal detectors at around the 0:36 mark in the trailer below, and you can see other characters being swallowed up by the sandpit at around the 0:52 mark.